# Setting 'DF'-bit in IP-header inside pcap file

Tags: linux, networking, ip, ipv4, pcap

There is some *`.pcap`*-file with fragmented IP traffic. I replay this file with `tcpreplay`, but also I need to replay it with [*`DF`*](https://www.eit.lth.se/ppplab/IPHeader.htm#Flags) *(don't fragment)* bit set in some packets.

I supposed that `tcprewrite` will help, but it seems that there is no ability to change IP-header flags in this utility.

So which utility (console preferably) should I use to correctly alter IP-header flags in pcap-file in Linux? If `tcprewrite` or any other can do so, some examples would be helpful.

By the way, after altering *`DF`*-bit the [checksum](https://www.eit.lth.se/ppplab/IPHeader.htm#Header%20checksum) of IP-header should be updated respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various methods I would approach this.

If there aren't many packets, or it's a onetime change, I really like [WireEdit](https://wireedit.com/), [TraceWrangler](https://www.tracewrangler.com/) is another GUI option.

Otherwise, two options if you have any programming experience, are [Scapy](https://scapy.net/)(python), and [PcapPlusPlus](https://seladb.github.io/PcapPlusPlus-Doc/tutorial_packet_craft_n_edit.html#packet_editing)(C++). This PcapPlusPlus link might be enough of a tutorial of what you are trying to do, that with very little programming experience you can do what you want.

Finally, I found [bittwist](http://bittwist.sourceforge.net/doc/bittwiste.1.html) that is an older application, but has the `-f d` option.

```
       -f flags
                 Control flags. Possible characters for flags are:

                 - : remove all flags
                 r : set the reserved flag
                 d : set the donâ€™t fragment flag
                 m : set the more fragment flag

                 Example: -f d
                 If  any of the flags is specified, all original flags are
                 removed automatically.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `bittwist` (ver. 2.0) installed either from *`jessie main`* or from *`wheezy-backports`* (as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/720354/debian-install-package-bittwist))  has no `-f` option at all despite its man on site.